# Cleanup badge for rolling back your own edit?

Tags: support, badges, editing, cleanup-badge, rollbacks

I just got a cleanup badge for editing a post, realizing I may have jumped the gun, and rolling it back to the previous post. Seem weird to get credit for rolling back my own edit:

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/4/cleanup?userid=603

Doesn't it make more sense to only get a cleanup badge for rolling back someone else's edit?

Comment: @Hod Sounds more like [meta-tag:feature-request]/[meta-tag:bug] to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA Not a [tag:feature-request], I think, although I could get behind [tag:bug].

Comment: Copy of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61855

Comment: @msh210 Isn't that an answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I see no answer there from an SE employee, so I can't say what SE might say about this were it a [meta-tag:feature-request]/[meta-tag:bug]. The answer given there is an answer to this [meta-tag:support] question, but I'm not sure I agree with it so am not posting a link to it as an answer here.